# If not a log-normal distribution, what distribution describes this data?

Tags: probability-distributions

I have some empirical data which appeared to be best fit to a log-normal, but upon making a histogram of log(x) with 50 bins I got this result which appears to have some skew:

[image]

What is the proper distribution to use for data whose log looks like the plot above? Some sort of "log-normal with skew"? How would I fit the data in this case?

Note: I believe [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3023050/shift-of-log-normal-distribution-and-skewness-of-associated-gaussian) is a similar one, but with no answer yet.

Comment: (1) All log-normal distributions are right-skewed. (2) Most real-life distributions do not exactly fit any of the well-know theoretical distributions

Comment: the histogram represents log(data), I will add labels to make it more clear

Comment: What is the source of your data? Anyway, if you wanna know, if the given data is distributed according to some function, you should perform a $\chi^2$-test...